# selecting multiple files in CKFinder 3 integrated on CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckfinder

I'm using CKFinder 3 integration with CKEditor. Now, I want to select multiple files on the CKFinder window and want them to get added on the CKEditor link dialog.

Currently, even if I'm selecting multiple files, only one file is getting added.

Can anyone know how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is the CKFinder which by default sends only a single URL to the CKEditor. You would need to try changing this behavior using below two events:

- https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-event-files_choose
- https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-event-file_choose_resizedImage

Another problem is CKEditor. Whenever you select an image or a file in CKFinder a corresponding link (anchor tag) or image (img tag) is being created and inserted into CKEditor. Both link and image plugins support single insertion so you would need to write new plugins which insert multiple links and images.

This is a lot of custom coding.

Comment: thank you... Recently I found out the same thing. And I'm planning to implement a custom plugin which will call ckfinder popup and edit ckfinder.js to send multiple files back to the editor.